# Field correlation with date constraint

Tags: sql, date, constraints, correlation, date-comparison

We're stuck in a huge challenge here. Let's assume the tables of one db were not properly planned in first hand. That's what it is and I need a solution for that.

There's a table A with 2 fields. Let's think that I have an assistant that supports my job every day, but i just registered when he/she started to assist me. It means the 'Stop Date' (not existent in the table) of each Assistant is the day before the Start Date of the next one.

```
Assistant | Start Date
James     | 07/01/17
Frank     | 01/03/18
Erika     | 01/06/18
```

There's a second table B with that registers how many hours my assistant worked:

```
Date      | Worked Hours
12/31/17  | 7.5    
01/01/18  | 7.5     
01/02/18  | 9        
01/03/18  | 8       
01/04/18  | 9        
01/05/18  | 7.5 
01/06/18  | 9 
01/07/18  | 10
```

Given the information above, I need to write a SQL to return a table like below, considering the Start Dates of each person:

```
Assistant | Date     | Worked Hours
```

Basically I need to correlate somehow the Date and Start Date to return the Assistant, but it involve's date comparisons that I have no idea how to do.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Add a column assistant_id to table 2.

Comment: Which database are u using?

Comment: Is "Start Date" and  "Date" have DateTime datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*,
       (select a.assistant
        from a
        where a.date <= b.date
        order by a.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as assistant
from b;
```

Note all databases support the ANSI standard `fetch first 1 row only`, so you may need to use `limit` or `top` or whatever is appropriate for your database.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!! I've tested Gordon's answer and it worked fine for me! But I'll have a try in the other methods and compare the performance! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

- use 'lead()' to find the *next* record
- use `infinity` to keep the final interval unclosed

---

```
CREATE TABLE a
        ( assistant text primary key
        , startdate date
        );

SET datestyle = 'mdy';

insert into a(assistant,startdate) VALUES
 ('James', '07/01/17' )
,('Frank', '01/03/18' )
,('Erika', '01/06/18' )
        ;
CREATE TABLE b
        ( ddate      DATE NOT NULL primary key
        , workedhours DECIMAL(4,1)
        );
insert into b(ddate,workedhours) VALUES
('12/31/17', 7.5)
,('01/01/18', 7.5)
,('01/02/18', 9)
,('01/03/18', 8)
,('01/04/18', 9)
,('01/05/18', 7.5)
,('01/06/18', 9)
,('01/07/18', 10)
        ;
```

---

```
WITH aa AS (
        SELECT a.assistant
        , a.startdate
        , lead(a.startdate, 1, 'infinity'::date) OVER (ORDER BY a.startdate)
                 AS enddate
        FROM a
        )
-- SELECT * FROM a ; 
SELECT aa.startdate, aa.enddate, aa.assistant
        , SUM(b.workedhours) AS workedhours
FROM aa
LEFT JOIN b ON b.ddate >= aa.startdate
                AND b.ddate < aa.enddate
GROUP BY 1,2,3
        ;
```

---

Output:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
SET
INSERT 0 3
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 8
 startdate  |  enddate   | assistant | workedhours 
------------+------------+-----------+-------------
 2017-07-01 | 2018-01-03 | James     |        24.0
 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-06 | Frank     |        24.5
 2018-01-06 | infinity   | Erika     |        19.0
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Assistant VARCHAR(10), [Start Date] DATE)
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
('James','07/01/17'),
('Frank','01/03/18'),
('Erika','01/06/18')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE ([Date] DATE, [Worked Hours] DECIMAL(18,2))
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES
('12/31/17', 7.5),   
('01/01/18', 7.5),    
('01/02/18', 9  ),     
('01/03/18', 8  ),    
('01/04/18', 9  ),     
('01/05/18', 7.5),
('01/06/18', 9  ),
('01/07/18', 10 )


;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Start Date] DESC)
FROM 
    @TableA A
    INNER JOIN @TableB B ON A.[Start Date] <= B.Date
)
select Assistant, Date,  [Worked Hours] FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
Assistant  Date       Worked Hours
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------
James      2017-12-31 7.50
James      2018-01-01 7.50
James      2018-01-02 9.00
Frank      2018-01-03 8.00
Frank      2018-01-04 9.00
Frank      2018-01-05 7.50
Erika      2018-01-06 9.00
Erika      2018-01-07 10.00
```